# Tolerance interval for Poisson

Tags: poisson-distribution, tolerance-interval

I am an R user and need to figure out how to compute a tolerance interval for a Poisson distribution with lambda = 120. I would like to get a 1-sided upper tolerance interval with alpha = 0.05 and proportion = 0.99.

Comment: If you already know $\lambda$, you don't need a tolerance interval.  $\alpha$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Do you mean you have estimated $\lambda$ from the data ?